# How can I calculate weekly average sales over a 4 week period in Progress / open edge?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress and I would like to know, 
How do I write the code to find out a product weekly average sales over a 4 week period ?

so far I have tried

```
for each Product no-lock
    where sale-date GE 03/01/2018
    and sale-date LE 05/30/2018
    Break by sale-date:

Display Product-cost(average)
```

Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site and not a code writing service. So please describe what you already tried and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, how ever like I said I am new to the subject and i am still learning how to ask question the Progress way.  I have added code to aid what I am trying to ask.  Thank you.

Comment: You could have a look at the "ACCUMULATE statement" entry in the OpenEdge Help. The AVERAGE phrase should help you. The SUB-AVERAGE looks useful for your case, but at the moment I have no idea how to break for weeks. A sub-average for each month should work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break by sale` date will give you a "break" indication per date. For weekly dates you will have to group your query otherwise, either with a field indicating week number or by some other method.

One way could be to run individual dates via a procedure taking a start and end date.

About calculating averages there are built in functions that accumulate numbers. `ACCUMULATE`, `ACCUM`, `AVERAG` and so on. I wouldn't bother though. I would count number of records and sum up sales and then divide.

Something like this (using bogus table and field names):
DEFINE VARIABLE iNum AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iSum AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

```
PROCEDURE sales:
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pFrom AS DATE NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pTo AS DATE NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER piNum AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER piSum AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

    FOR EACH sales NO-LOCK WHERE sales.date >= pFrom 
                             AND sales.date <= pTo :
      piNum = piNum + 1.
      piSum = piSum + sales.value.
   END.
END.

RUN sales (03/01/2018, 03/08/2018, OUTPUT iNum, OUTPUT iSum).

DISPLAY iNum iSum iSum / iNum LABEL "Average".
```

Comment: I generally avoid the accumulate functions too since I can never get their syntax right in one go. But you have to admit that they look clean:

https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5c1c1f88689ac207d737508d

:-)